# Submit search form to another page to its iframe

Tags: forms, iframe, form-submit

Is it possible that when submit search form to **Page A** to forward search form to **Page B** to its iframe and load **Page B** with search results in iframe ?

Actually if I search on **Page A** it loads iframe page with results but I need to load **Page B** with results in iframe.

Here is the test Page A http://mysite.com/lidl/page1.html and Page B http://mysite.com/lidl/page2.html

Page#1 search form:

```
<form id="SearchForm" action="http://mysite.com/search-results-jobs/" target="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="listing_type[equal]" value="Job" />
    <label>
        <strong>What?</strong> 
        <em><input type="text" value="job title, keywords or company name" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='job title, keywords or company name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='job title, keywords or company name' ) this.value=''" name="keywords [all_words]" /></em>
    </label>
    <label>
        <strong class="color">Where?</strong>
        <b><input type="text" value="city, state or zip code"  onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='city, state or zip code'" onFocus="if(this.value =='city, state or zip code' ) this.value=''" name="City[all_words]" /></b>
    </label>
    <a href="#" class="SearchForm-link" onclick="document.getElementById('SearchForm').submit()"/>Search</a>
</form>
```

Page#2

```
<form id="SearchForm" action="http://mysite.com/search-results-jobs/" target="my-iframe" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="listing_type[equal]" value="Job" />
    <label>
        <strong>What?</strong>
        <em><input type="text" value="job title, keywords or company name" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='job title, keywords or company name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='job title, keywords or company name' ) this.value=''" name="keywords[all_words]" /></em></label>
    <label>
        <strong class="color">Where?</strong>
        <b><input type="text" value="city, state or zip code" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='city, state or zip code'" onFocus="if(this.value =='city, state or zip code' ) this.value=''" name="City[all_words]" /></b>
    </label>
    <a href="#" class="SearchForm-link" onclick="one(); two(); three(); four();">Search</a>
    <input type="submit" id="btn-search" class="button" value="Cauta"/>
</form>
<iframe id="my-iframe" name="my-iframe" align="right" src="http://mysite.com" frameborder="0" height="100%" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: What's the point of forwarding the form to another identical form? Why not fill out form B directly?

Comment: Home page will have stunning design, while search result page will be typical.

Answer (score 0):

The usual technique used by search engines is to pass the query in the url. Here is an example with Monster (search for JavaScript in San Diego, CA):

```
http://jobsearch.monster.com/search/?q=JavaScript&where=San-Diego__2C-CA
```

Google also works like this, etc.

You could apply this to your own pages, to easily pass the query from A to B.

An added benefit is that people can send query results by e-mail.

Comment: And the hammer kicks in my had.. Well, I'm just a newbie trying to fix this issue in the most easy effective way. The software script behind is made in Smarty, this is why I rather use it as Iframe because its hard to redesign it completely. If you can help me with above code to add the correct script to make it work as need it I would be greatful forever.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help here. Maybe update your post and tags with this info?